# What are suitable vector.control versions for postgresql12?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgvector

I installed postgresql12 on ubuntu and created a database called my_db.
But I want to install the vector plugin in my_db.

Use the command CREATE EXTENSION vector directly in my_db; An error will be reported:
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/vector.control":  No such file or directory
I refer to the link https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector, I download the vector control file and copy it to/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/path, but still an error: ERROR: extension "vector" has no installation script nor update path for version "0.5.1".
So I wanted to ask which versions of vector.control are suitable for postgresql12?

Comment: You need to install the pgvector package as a whole, not just grab bits and pieces at random. If it isn't available in ubuntu's repos (probably not) or the postgresql.org repos (haven't checked) then follow https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#installation

Comment: Thank you！But I have installed the whole package at “/tmp/...“ successfully.  I'm not sure if installing it in this location makes any difference.

Comment: You can't install something in /tmp/ - that doesn't really make any sense as a statement.